# Association for one model belonging to two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

Which type of rails association should I use for this scenario?

A Question has many Answers, and a User also has many Answers.

A polymorphic association seems very close, but I need the Answer to the Question and the Answer that the User gives to point to **the same object.**  It seems different from example on the [association guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) because in that example the Picture object is different for an Employee and a Product.  Using their example, I need an Employee's picture and a Product's picture to be **the same Picture.**

I think I need a structure like

```
-----------------------------------------------
answer_id | question_id | user_id | answer_text
-----------------------------------------------
|    1    |      5      |    10   |   stuff   |
|    2    |      3      |    6    |   stuff 2 |
|    3    |      2      |    10   |   stuff 3 |
```

I could make answers belong to questions, and add the user_id manually, but that doesn't feel very "railsy."

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: So in your structure, does the user_id represent the user that answered the question or user_id represent the user who asked the question?

Comment: The user_id is the User that answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work for you?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :question
 belongs_to :user
end
```

You table structure will be like

```
answers
   -question_id
   -user_id
   -answer_text
```

Comment: Hmm maybe I was over thinking it in my head.  Would I be able to do User.answers and Question.answers and retrieve the same Answer object?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Tables structure:

- **questions**: id, question_text
- **users**: id, name
- **answers**: id, user_id, question_id, answer_text